# Getting addClass() to run after an Ajax call (within a Drupal views table)

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-6

I've got a table, created by Views. I'm adding a class with jQuery to some of the links, something like:

```
$('div.view-marketplace-items .views-field-title a').addClass('test');
```

The table uses Ajax, both with a pager and with sortable table headers. **What I need to do is make sure the above code runs every time the pager is used or the headers are sorted.**

I've seen a function `live()`, but this seems to be for binding event handlers.

I *think* I may need to use Drupal.behaviors, but I'm all out of brain cells at the mo in trying to understand how these work... :)

Cheers,
James

Comment: try to ask on http://drupal.stackexchange.com , I'm sure you'll find someone to explain you how to configure a drupal behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the class by theming the view field with php, or else via it's rewrite options in the UI. Or else if you want to use jquery, drupal.behaviors are designed to run after JS DOM changes so you may have more success using a wrapper like

```
Drupal.behaviors.mymoduleAddClass = function(){
 $('div.view-marketplace-items .views-field-title a').addClass('test');
}
```